# How to set the PIO cycle timing of an IDE ATA controller?

Tags: c++, windows, io, driver, hardware

I can transfer data in PIO mode under windows 8 x64 with a driver I wrote myself to access I/O ports. Even if I set the transfer mode of the target hard disk (using ATA commands) to PIO 4, the transfer speed (of a read operation) doesn't go above 1.2 MB/s (out of ~16 MB/s that PIO mode 4 should reach). The strange thing is that even if I set the disk to PIO 0 or 1, the speed remains the same. 
This is what makes me think that I have to change the IDE controller cycle time. But WHERE? Which port(s)? Let's say I have a standard IDE controller, with two channels, and I'm working on channel 0, ports 0x1F0 to 0x1F7 for ATA registers, port 3F6 for alternate status register/device control and ports FFA0 to FFAF for BusMaster. I know that for PIO 4 I should use a cycle time of 120 ns instead of the 600 ns of PIO 0 but, where am I supposed to set the different timings?

Comment: How do you measure this?  Disk transfers are very bursty, you have to wait until the platter spins to the right position.  Don't measure the latency.

Comment: @HansPassant
Have a look at the table at [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programmed_input/output)

Comment: how to  set the transfer mode of the target hard disk? I can not find the correct command from the hard disk datasheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question depends on what sort of IDE controller you have in your machine, because setting the host timing is not part of the ATA spec.  For a specific example, if you are using the built-in IDE ports on one of the Intel ICHx chips, then the register that controls the IDE timing is at offsets 0x40 to 0x41 in the PCI config space associated with the controller. Several other manufacturers have also adopted this same register for the same purpose.

So you can try sticking 0x33 into this register and see if the I/O speeds up - if it does, then you have a controller that handles this convention.

0x0- IORDY sampled at 5 clocks
0x1- IORDY sampled at 4 clocks
0x2- IORDY sampled at 3 clocks
0x3- IORDY sampled at 2 clocks

0x-0 tRecovery 4 clocks
0x-1 tRecovery 3 clocks
0x-2 tRecovery 2 clocks
0x-3 tRecovery 1 clocks

In practice, using 0x33 should work with any modern drive.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is correct. However I found that on modern Intel PCH (ICH are old generations) that registers, as per Intel Serie 7 Chipset PCH documentation, have actually no effect on hardware and are kept R/W only for software compatibility.